# How to do an ls command on output from an awk field

Tags: bash, unix, awk, ls

This takes a directory as a parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l $1 |awk '$3!=$4{print $9}'
```

Now what I need is to be able to do ANOTHER `ls -l` on the just the files that are found from the awk statement.

Yeah, it sounds dumb, and I know of like 3 other ways to do this, but not with awk.

Comment: Why do you need to do another `ls`? Why don't you just print the results from the first `ls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l $1 | awk '$3!=$4{ system( "ls -l '$1'/" $9}'
```

Comment: won't work, ls doesn't prefix the directory when listing directory contents... and, since it's a homework question, try not to give the solution directly. :)

Comment: I was trying variations of this earlier and gave up after about 20 minutes because I couldn't figure out how to get the parameter entered from the command line ($1) to be represented in the awk statement.  (Because I need the entire directory to be represented, not just the $9 but the 'directory passed as a parameter/$9'

Comment: @roger34 Does this edit work for you?  Note that this will fail if $1 contains spaces, but paths should never have spaces...

Comment: It most certainly does work! (once you put the other parentheses in) You are my hero.

Comment: @William Pursell - any why is that? "paths should never have spaces"?

Comment: Because space is the classic delimiter used to separate words, and putting spaces in a file name greatly increases the difficulty of working with files with very little benefit.

Comment: Personally I see scripts which don't handle spaces (and other strange characters) as broken. Handling it is basic thing to do - if you're not doing it properly, you're one step closer to doing bad things in case someone creates a file with "clever" name. It's the same situation as with validating user input in web apps. You have to do it, or you'll end up with problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk system command:

```
ls -l $1 |awk '$3!=$4{system("ls -l " $9)}'
```

Comment: I saw roe's comment, and also there are issues if the file names have embedded spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The command to use is `xargs`.

```
man xargs
```

should give some clues.

Comment: What roe said. I can't seem to get the syntax down for having the directory precede the files found.  (ex. the parameter is /home/userx/    and the files found are foo.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt)

Comment: @roe, @roger34 - if you don't mind skipping hidden files, you can just add a trailing `/*` to `$1`. This way, `$9` should display the whole path.

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to adjust the first `ls -l` you could try to do:

```
ls -ld "$1"/* |awk '$3!=$4{print $9}' | xargs ls -l
```

In this case `ls` will prefix the directory. But I don't know if this is portable behavior.